# convertir canvas.toDataURL a imagen y subirla servidor

Tags: php, javascript, html5, php7

ok, quería el resultado de un canvas que convertí a Data url, lo cuál es lo siguiente, que inicia, porque es un código muy largo

```
data:image/png;base64,iVB...
```

//JavaScript

```
document.user.userImgPhp.value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
```

//HTML

`<input type="hidden" name="userImgPhp">`

//PHP

```
$img = $index->limpiarDatos($_POST['userImgPhp']);
if (!empty($img)) {
  $nameImg = $nick.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  imagepng($img,$nameImg);
  $archivo_subido = '../' . $blog_config['carpeta_imagenes'] . 'users/' . $nameImg;
  move_uploaded_file($img,$archivo_subido);
} else {

}
```

Había estado leyendo que se puede convertir con la función de imagepng() y creo que sí, así se crean las imagenes pero también quiero subirlas al servidor como imagen para así ser llamadas por el nombre, guardado en la base de datos y todo eso. Creo que me dí a entender, si alguien entiende de lo que hablo y sea amable de explicarme lo agradecería de verdad

Comment: Pero no termino de entender cómo subirlo al servidor con PHP, el vato usa AJAX y quería hacerlo desde netamente PHP

Comment: $nameImg = $nick.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $datos = base64_decode(preg_replace('/^[^,]*,/', '', $img));
                $imagen = file_put_contents($nameImg, $datos);
                /* $imagenC = imagepng($img,$nameImg); */
                $archivo_subido = '../' . $blog_config['carpeta_imagenes'] . 'users/' . $nameImg;
                move_uploaded_file($imagen,$archivo_subido);

Comment: Intenté hacerlo de esta manera también con esa cosa pero me dice Warning: file_put_contents(padrocha2019-05-27 14:28:08): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\Zblog\user\edit_user.php on line 95

Comment: AJAX es la forma de mandar datos del cliente (HTML+JS) al servidor (PHP). Vos le pasarías esa imagen base64 mediante una petición y luego en el servidor resolvés de convertirlo en imagen, guardarlo en el servidor y en la DB.

Comment: Pues sí, pero es que todo lo tengo dentro de un sólo formulario para actualizar la información del usuario, no sé si se podría hacer de esa forma

Comment: Nel, ya descubrí como, estaba poniendo solo el nombre de la imagen cuando se tenía que poner toda la ruta, gracias de todas formas